# Save and read int - android

Tags: android, save, int

I'm making a settings screen using an int to set the background of my app. It works just fine... inside the current activity. But as soon as I leave the activity, the int value is lost and the background isn't changed.

**what I want to do:** I want to save the int from my settings activity, and then import it to my other activites and check if the int "bak" equals null, "bg", "bg1" or "bg2".

I've heard of sharedPreferences but never got it working. That is why I open a new thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, add these global variables

```
SharedPreferences data;
public static String filename = "whateveryou want";
```

initialize it in onCreate

```
data = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
```

then to add something to it, use this, with `"key"` being a unique descriptor and `name` being the variable name you want to store

```
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
        editor.putInt("key", name);
        editor.commit();
```

access it by this, where `default` is what you want the variable to be assigned if no preference exists.

```
intVariable = data.getInt("key", default);
```

EDIT:

I noticed you want to use letters, eg bg1 etc. To do that you need to use a String, or use an int with a switch case or multiple if statements. Here's a switch case example you can modify. Just make sure to put the switch case statement **after** you access the SharedPreference in the previous code block.

```
switch (integerVariable){
    case 1: // if the intagerVariable = 1, notice the : not a ;
        // set background to BG1
    break;
    case 2: // if the intagerVariable = 2, notice the : not a ;
        // set background to BG2
    break;
}
```

Just add as many case statements as needed.

Comment: Will the int be named "key" when imported or does it keep it's previous name? (Bak)

Comment: you import it with whatever name you name it, and it'll be named whatever variable you use for `name = getString(key, default)`

Comment: THX! It worked in my code. an advice to anyone going to use this code though is to remember that pass.edit(); should be replaced by (in this case) data.edit(); or you'll just wonder what's wrong with "pass".